# Which stat is applied first, Damage Reduction or Damage Threshold in Fallout New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

The information found on the Fallout Wikia seems to be conflicting.

Under the **Damage Threshold** article, it states that:

```
The combined statistics of DT and DR (with DT being applied first) determines....
```

whereas on the **Damage Resistance** article:

```
Damage resistance is applied before damage threshold.
```

*I am confused. Which one is really applied first?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact Fallout NV damage formula is as follows:

```
DAMAGE_TO_TARGET = ( DMG + (CRITDMG x BC) - DT )x SA x HS x AM x DM x PERK_MULTIPLIERS 

DMG = Unmodified weapon base damage. DAM is equal to DMG with a weapon at full repair, 100 weapon skill and no damage modifying perks 
CRITDMG = Unmodified bonus damage added for critical strike on target 
SA = Sneak Attack modifier adds +100% total damage 
BC = Better Criticals modifier adds +50% critical damage 
HS = Headshot modifier adds +100% total damage 
DT = Damage Threshold of target 
AM = Ammo type multiplier 
DM = Difficulty multiplier. One on normal difficulty, 0.5 on very hard. 
PERK_MULTIPLIERS = Other damage multipliers from perks such as Lord of Death, Bloody Mess and Living Anatomy (and all damage resistance perks fall under this category)
```

As you can see, DT is subtracted directly from weapon damage whereas the resistance is a multiplier after the fact.  This means that DT is applied first. ([source](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_combat)]

Comment: However there is only one item in the game which adds DR unless more were added with Lonesome Road. That being the rebreather at 3 DR.