# Are perk modifiers to weapon damage added before or after DT is applied?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

The [combat damage formula on the wiki](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_combat#Combat_damage) seems to indicate that perk bonuses to combat damage is added after DT has been applied. However if I take the Cowboy perk the dam stat on the weapon is increased by 25% suggesting that this bonus is applied before DT. The same is true for Bloody Mess, Lord Death, Pyromaniac etc.

If it's applied directly to the base damage it won't be applied to the bonus damage from critical hits, however if it's applied after DT then the effect is smaller for normal hits than it would be if it was applied before DT.

I'm assuming that either the UI shows misleading damage values, or perks like Cowboy that increases specific weapon damage is added to the base damage of the weapon instead of at the end. What is correct?

Comment: Related: [Which stat is applied first, Damage Reduction or Damage Threshold in Fallout New Vegas?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/30925/4797)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perk modifiers are added before DT is applied.

I decided to do some basic testing in game using the console to add/remove perks and adjust skill levels. The Fallout wiki I linked in my question contains the wrong formula. However the [GECK wiki](https://geckwiki.com/index.php/Weapon_Damage_Formula) seems to agree with my findings:

> Gun Damage = (PerkModifiers(BaseWeaponDamage * DamageMultiplier * GunConditionPenalty * SkillBonus) + CriticalDamageBonus) - DamageAbsorbedByArmor

My testing showed that:

- Weapon condition and skill is applied to the base damage of the weapon first.
- Then crit damage is added (if it was a critical hit) applying the perk bonus from better criticals only to the crit portion of the damage.
- Then perks are applied
- Finally DT is applied